# Applying Mean to log2 Values, the right thing to do?

Tags: logistic, mean

I have set of values (n=10), over two conditions.
Condition_X - 5 Measurements 
Condition_Y - 5 Measurements

These values are in log2 space.

if I take the mean of each condition and subtract to get the difference (ratio in linear space), i.e. mean(Condition_X) - mean(Condition_Y), and then convert to linear space, i.e. 2^(mean(Condition_X) - mean(Condition_Y)). Is that the same as taking values in linear space and doing mean(Condition_X_Linear) / mean(Condition_Y_Linear)??

I'm not sure if taking the mean of log2 values is doing what I think it's doing.

Any clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try it? This is such a small problem, you can easily compute both mean differences and look if they are the same.

Comment: I can, it was a shower thought this morning, just someone might have some insight. I can do the calculation when I get into work.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the same thing". What are you ultimately trying to achieve?